# IIS URL rewrite not working, the input URL not even captured?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, proxy, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

The Failed Request Tracing works fine to log failed rewritings. I can view the log files and at least understand why the rewriting not working.

The regex pattern has passed a matching test OK, but the input URLs I enter in the browser are not even captured. All the URLs mapped to controller actions are captured (my website is an ASP.NET MVC app) however the URL I need to be rewritten is not mapped to any, the page shows 404. But I expect it to be rewritten to some working URL (to test it out, so that instead of showing 404, it should be rewritten to the target url and shows the returned content from there).

My URL rewriting rule uses a `Reverse Proxy` template.

I hope what I understand here is correct. How can I diagnose this? My purpose is just to do something like turning IIS into a reverse proxy by capturing all requests through my website, check if any matching the defined regex pattern before requesting to the rewritten URL and returning back the content to the original client.

### Update

For those who may not know about ASP.NET MVC:

Suppose my website has a controller called `HomeController` with action `Index` and the URL mapped to it is `/Home/Index`.

The URL I mean **not mapped to any action** here may be `/Home/TestProxy`
Here the `HomeController` does not expose any action `TestProxy` and also there is not any routing rule maps `/Home/TestProxy` to any action. So in this case the ASP.NET MVC app will shows a `404` page.

As I said above, for the URLs mapped to a valid controller action, they seem to be captured and considered as **input URLs** (before being checked against the rewriting rule). But for URLs not mapped to any controller action (showing 404), I don't see any logged as input URLs (so of course they will not be checked against the rewriting rule and it won't work).

### Update 2

Actually my tested URL is not even mapped to a controller so looks like it's not logged by the **Failed Requests Tracing** rule I setup. Now I've tried using a URL mapped to a controller but not to any action (it still shows 404) but successfully logged by the Failed Request Tracing rule. I can see this in the log file:

```
<EventData>
   <Data Name="ContextId">{80000034-0000-F000-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
   <Data Name="Pattern">testproxy/(.*)</Data>
   <Data Name="Input">home/testproxy/index</Data>
   <Data Name="Negate">false</Data>
   <Data Name="Matched">true</Data>
</EventData>
```

So it reported a `matched` pattern, but still the page shows 404, whereas I expected it to return the content from the rewritten url (which should be `http://10.0.0.5/index` - I confirm that this URL works if requested directly, it's just another simple published website on local network). I don't even know if this is possible now or I did something wrong here.

Comment: Keep in mind no one here can see your screen, so when you talked about "the URL I need to be rewritten is not mapped to any", show that (screen shots, video or whatever suitable). You should also show the rules in case common mistakes are there.

Comment: @LexLi I mean the URL is not mapped to any **controller action**, isn't that just clear? In such a case my website shows a 404. I don't think it need to be specific in this case

Comment: @LexLi please see my **UPDATE** section above, if you downvoted this question, please consider removing your vote, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

URL rewrite inbound rule get executed before controller action.It is appreciated if you could post full error message in your Failed request tracing log.

If the request http://10.0.0.5/index but return 404 from IIS. It sounds like your ARR proxy was not enabled at all. First of all, please try to disable reverse proxy outbound rule. Then go to IIS manager->server node->application request routing cache->Server proxy setting->Enable proxy.

Update:

The rewrite rule has worked and it seems that the request was stopped by

[HttpException]: The controller for path '/questions/62078944/iis-url-rewrite-not-working-the-input-url-not-even-captured' was not found or does not implement IController.
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
-->"

Comment: Now I can just say that the `Enable proxy` is checked, let me inspect it more and get back to you later. In the mean time, if possible, please look into my **UPDATE 2** section above, the request is logged but still the url rewirting does not seem to work. You may need more info to diagnose it out, at this time I just hope you may give me possible next steps to do. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Hopeless Please open failed request tracing log via IE instead of xml format and post the full rewrite section and full error message.

Comment: The original cause for the 404 request not being logged is due to wrong setting for the captured status codes (when setting up the tracing rule). I modified it and now the request is logged fine. However the rewriting does not seem to work. As you suggested, I've tried opening the xml file via IE and see that no message is reported, it looks like this `No Errors or Warnings were found` Of course there are a lot of other data about the request (in `Request Details` tab).

Comment: @Hopeless Please switch to compact view and post rewrite sections and the module return error. Of course, it is appreciated if you could share the log.

Comment: I see some sign of `pattern matched` and `new url written` in the log but still not sure why it does not return to my browser. I'm trying to rewrite `http://localhost:80/...` to `http://stackoverflow.com/...` and hope that it returns the stackoverflow page. Here is the log file (zipped) https://sites.google.com/site/ngaodaantoi/files/fr000001.zip?attredirects=0&d=1

Comment: @Hopeless The rule has already worked. It looks like your application is trying to overide the response body .The controller for path '/questions/62078944/iis-url-rewrite-not-working-the-input-url-not-even-captured' was not found or does not implement IController.

Comment: yes I can see that bottom entry, the input url is of course not mapped to any controller (as mentioned in my question). I guess if it is mapped to a controller action, the result will be shown normally (not from stackoverflow)? So that's not what I want. It's strange that the url is rewritten from `/questions/...` to `stackoverflow.com/questions/...` but after that it rewrites back to `/questions/...` from `stackoverflow.com/questions/...`. That might be why it's not working, not sure why it behaves like that.